# Python pandas: Generate Document-Term matrix from whitespace delimited '.dat' file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, document

I'm using Python to attempt to rank documents using an [Okapi BM25 model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25).

I think that I can calculate some of the terms required for the `Score(D,Q)` such as the IDF (Inverse Document Frequency) in a more efficient way (i.e: Counting all non-zero rows for a particular term (column)). Furthermore, I can add a new column to the matrix for the actual Score and then sort by this to rank documents.

The document term vectors are stored in a `.dat` file which is structured like the following:

```
D1 7:10 2:5
D2 1:2 3:4
```

where `D1` is a document ID and `7:10` represents the term with ID `7` appearing `10` times

At the moment, I am reading it into a list of lists using the following code:

```
fname = "dtv.dat"
f = open(fname, "r")
l = [x.strip(" \n").split(" ") for x in f.readlines()]
```

which yields the following output for the given example:

```
[['D1', '7:10', '2:5'],['D2' '1:2', '3:4']]
```

Given this list of list format, what is the most efficient way to convert this to a Python pandas DataFrame similar to the following:

```
0      1     2      3      7
D1     0     5      0      10    
D2     2     0      4      0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer seems to be ok if each document appears only once in the file. Otherwise, the code will overwrite some records in dict `d`.

I think the following would be more general:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

fname = 'example.txt'

full_list = []
with open(fname, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        arr = line.strip(" \n").split(" ")
        for chunk in arr[1:]:
            # converting numbers to ints:
            int_pair = [int(x) for x in chunk.split(":")]
            full_list.append([arr[0], *int_pair])

df = pd.DataFrame(full_list)

df2 = df.pivot_table(values = 2, index = 0, columns = 1, aggfunc = np.sum, fill_value = 0)
```

How it works:

```
>>> cat 'example.txt'
D1 1:3 2:2 3:3
D2 1:4 2:7 
D2 7:1
D1 2:4 4:2
D1 4:1 4:3
>>> full_list
Out[37]: 
[['D1', 1, 3],
 ['D1', 2, 2],
 ['D1', 3, 3],
 ['D2', 1, 4],
 ['D2', 2, 7],
 ['D2', 7, 1],
 ['D1', 2, 4],
 ['D1', 4, 2],
 ['D1', 4, 1],
 ['D1', 4, 3]]
>>> df
Out[38]: 
    0  1  2
0  D1  1  3
1  D1  2  2
2  D1  3  3
3  D2  1  4
4  D2  2  7
5  D2  7  1
6  D1  2  4
7  D1  4  2
8  D1  4  1
9  D1  4  3
>>> df2
Out[39]: 
1   1  2  3  4  7
0                
D1  3  6  3  6  0
D2  4  7  0  0  1
```

Comment: Wow, very nice indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to accomplish this using a combination of changing to a list of lists, converting the list of lists to a dictionary of ID and dictionary of term frequencies, then straight to DataFrame, any improvements very welcome!

```
def term_matrix(fname):
f = open(fname, "r")
l = [x.strip(" \n").split(" ") for x in f.readlines()]

d = dict()

for i in l:
    d[i[0]] = dict(t.split(":") for t in i[1:])

return pd.DataFrame(d).transpose()
```