# Read data (.dat file) with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I read the following (two columns) data (from a .dat file) with Pandas

```
TIME                      XGSM
2004 006 01 00 01 37 600  1
2004 006 01 00 02 32 800  5
2004 006 01 00 03 28 000  8
2004 006 01 00 04 23 200  11
2004 006 01 00 05 18 400  17
```

Column separator is (at least) 2 spaces.

I tried

```
df = pd.read_table("test.dat", sep="\s+", usecols=['TIME', 'XGSM'])
print df
```

But it prints

```
   TIME  XGSM
   2004     6
   2004     6
   2004     6
   2004     6
   2004     6
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python pandas: Generate Document-Term matrix from whitespace delimited '.dat' file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360906/python-pandas-generate-document-term-matrix-from-whitespace-delimited-dat-fi)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use parameter usecols with order of columns:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""TIME             XGSM
2004 006 01 00 01 37 600  1
2004 006 01 00 02 32 800  5
2004 006 01 00 03 28 000  8
2004 006 01 00 04 23 200  11
2004 006 01 00 05 18 400  17"""
#after testing replace StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), 
                 sep="\s+", 
                 skiprows=1, 
                 usecols=[0,7], 
                 names=['TIME','XGSM'])

print (df)
   TIME  XGSM
0  2004     1
1  2004     5
2  2004     8
3  2004    11
4  2004    17
```

Edit:

You can use separator `regex` - 2 and more spaces and then add `engine='python'` because warning:

> ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""TIME              XGSM
2004 006 01 00 01 37 600   1
2004 006 01 00 02 32 800   5
2004 006 01 00 03 28 000   8
2004 006 01 00 04 23 200   11
2004 006 01 00 05 18 400   17"""
#after testing replace StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep=r'\s{2,}', engine='python')

print (df)
                       TIME  XGSM
0  2004 006 01 00 01 37 600     1
1  2004 006 01 00 02 32 800     5
2  2004 006 01 00 03 28 000     8
3  2004 006 01 00 04 23 200    11
4  2004 006 01 00 05 18 400    17
```

Comment: Question edited to explicit say there are two columns there. The first column contains `2004 006 01 00 01 37 600`, i.e.

Answer (score 11):

Could also try `pd.read_fwf()` (*Read a table of fixed-width formatted lines into DataFrame*):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

pd.read_fwf(StringIO("""TIME                      XGSM
2004 006 01 00 01 37 600  1
2004 006 01 00 02 32 800  5
2004 006 01 00 03 28 000  8
2004 006 01 00 04 23 200  11
2004 006 01 00 05 18 400  17"""), usecols = ["TIME", "XGSM"])

#   TIME    XGSM
#0  2004    1
#1  2004    5
#2  2004    8
#3  2004    11
#4  2004    17
```

Comment: So if you dont pass widths does it automatically figure it out based on headers?

Comment: @ayhan. From the docs, it is using *the first 100 rows of the data* to detect the column specifications by default.

Answer (score 1):

I too experienced the problem while importing when there are lots of white space. I could solve by using

> pd.read_fwf(file_name)

If you want to import files with fixed width text file, then read_fwf might be the solution without needing to use StringIO.