# How to configure Pandas to read .dat file

Tags: pandas

Can't seem to load this file with pd.read_csv or pd.read_table:

```
http://cdsarc.u-strasbg.fr/ftp/cats/J/A+A/594/A27/psz2.dat
```

I've tried:

```
psz2_2017 = pd.read_csv('http://cdsarc.u-strasbg.fr/ftp/cats/J/A+A/594/A27/psz2.dat', sep=';', header=None)
```

Also tried pd.read_table with/wo `sep='\t'` (same result) and `sep='\s+'` (gets Error tokenizing data).

Results in:

```
0
0   1 PSZ2 G000.04+45.13 0.0405432 45.135175...
1   2 PSZ2 G000.13+78.04 0.1380577 78.042113...
2   3 PSZ2 G000.40-41.86 0.4029953 -41.860792...
```

Any suggestions?

The first line looks like this:

```
1 PSZ2 G000.04+45.13   0.0405432  45.1351750 229.1905120  -1.0172220  4.107310  6.75319 2 111 0     1 0 0.938825   5.481591  1.899500  20 RXC J1516.5-0056           0.119800  3.962411 0.393290 0.370242 J1516.5-0056 RMJ151653.9-010506.3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read data (.dat file) with Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41025416/read-data-dat-file-with-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `pd.read_fwf()`?

```
psz2_2017 =pd.read_fwf('http://cdsarc.u-strasbg.fr/ftp/cats/J/A+A/594/A27/psz2.dat',header=None)
```

Comment: @Luis Miguel How is `error_bad_lines=False` a key argument?  I don't see anything that indicates we would want to exclude incomplete lines.  Your solution returns1465 records, while mine returns 1653.

Comment: @luismiguel Where does it indicate 29 columns is the correct number?  Without context or some sort of metadata about the .dat file, I'm not sure how you can conclude either approach is better.  `pd.read_fwf()` decides on the optimal amount of white space by analyzing the first 100 lines of the data file, while `pd.read_csv()` uses only the first few lines.

Answer (score 1):

Your data has irregular columns, and pandas is trying to figure out the correct number by reading the first few lines and making the wrong inference.

This works:

```
psz2_2017 = pd.read_csv('http://cdsarc.u-strasbg.fr/ftp/cats/J/A+A/594/A27/psz2.dat',header = None, delim_whitespace=True, error_bad_lines=False )
```

The key argument here is ***error_bad_lines=False***