# How to convert .dat files into csv format that has multiple sheets using Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a `DAT` file which has two sheets in it and multiple columns in one sheet. I suspect that it is a binary file as I am not able to open it using a text editor and when I tried to export it into an excel file format using an internal software it showed that the `DAT` file has two sheets with one sheet containing some header information while the other sheet is in tabular form. I am now trying to convert these `DAT` files into `CSV` format using Python because I would like to convert all the files which I am not able to do so using the internal software.

I have tried a few sample codes that I could find here but it doesn't give me the expected results.

```
df = np.fromfile('test.DAT')
```

using the code above that somewhat worked, resulting in array forms as below without any header but I expect it to be in a tabular format.

```
array([6.01347002e-154, 6.01347037e-154, 3.91007023e+097, ...,
       0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000])
```

I am not sure how to deal with a `DAT` file that is resulting in 2 sheets when it is exported as an excel file. Any tips or help on this is much appreciated and I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Maybe pandas could be an approach. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41025416/read-data-dat-file-with-pandas) out and see if it helps :)

Comment: thanks, I manage to figure out that the file format is in .mdf mode. so now the issue is I need to find a way to convert these .mdf files that are saved as .dat files into .csv format

Comment: I have solved this problem by using the script below:
    yop = MDF(filename)
    df = yop.export('csv', filename = csv_folder)