# importing a dat file into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, import

I have a dat file downloaded from the below address:
[ratings](https://github.com/wesm/pydata-book/blob/1st-edition/ch02/movielens/ratings.dat)

I need to import it as a pandas dataframe. I've used the below code:

```
ratings = pd.read_csv('ratings.dat', sep='::', header=None, names['user_id', 'movie_id', 'rating', 'timestamp'])
```

But the datframe resulted as below which is false:
[image: ratings]

should I used another method to import dat files?
I've also checked the below link but that doesn't help me.
[Read data (.dat file) with Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41025416/read-data-dat-file-with-pandas)

Comment: It works for me... try to print `ratings` and see if this is the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Works well for me :

```
DAT=pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wesm/pydata-book/1st-edition/ch02/movielens/ratings.dat',
            sep='::', header=None, names=['user_id', 'movie_id', 'rating', 'timestamp'])
DAT.head(5)
```

Are you sure you read the proper file (the raw one from github) ?
The URL you mention doest not point to the proper file, use the raw one.

Comment: Actually I have saved the "ratings .dat" file into my hard drive (not the raw) and read that directly with pd.read_csv. But trying your way of accessing the file (I mean from that URL), things go right. What if I had no access to the URL and I had just the".dat" file?

Comment: Well then you should download the correct file (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wesm/pydata-book/1st-edition/ch02/movielens/ratings.dat)