# how to convert astropy.table.table.Table file type to pandas.core.frame.DataFrame file type

Tags: python, pandas, astropy

I have 10 files all of whcih are astropy.table.table.Table file type, all made of same six columns(mjd, filter, flux, flux_error, zp, zpsys) but have different lengths.
firstly I want to convert each file to pandas.core.frame.DataFrame file type so that I can add them all into one list and use the pd.concat function to turn all the 10 files into 1 big pandas.core.frame.DataFrame file.
I have tried this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from astropy.table import Table

n=10
li=[]
for i in range(0,n):
    file = "training_data/%s.dat"%i # This way I can call each file automatically
    data = Table.read(file, format="ascii") 
    data = pd.read_table(file) # I convert the file to pandas compatible
    li.append(data) # I add the file into the empty list above
    # now I have my list ready so I compress it into 1 file
all_data = pd.concat(li)
```

the problem with this method is the all the columns(6 columns) get compressed into 1 column for some reason, this makes it impossible for me to do the rest of the work.

when I check the shape of all_data I get (879, 1).
and it looks like this:

```
all_data.head()

    mjd filter flux flux_error zp zpsys
0   0.0 desg -4.386 4.679 27.5 ab
1   0.011000000005878974 desr -0.5441 2.751 27.5 ab
2   0.027000000001862645 desi 0.4547 4.627 27.5 ab
3   0.043000000005122274 desz -1.047 4.462 27.5 ab
4   13.043000000005122 desg -4.239 4.366 27.5 ab
```

so how I can I make a file like this but maintain my columns as separate columns?

here is an sample of some my data in file 0:

```
    mjd     filter  flux   flux_error zp    zpsys
    float64     str4    float64 float64 float64 str2
    0.0       desg      -4.386  4.679   27.5    ab
    0.0110000 desr  -0.5441 2.751   27.5    ab
    0.0270000 desi  0.4547  4.627   27.5    ab
    0.0430000 desz  -1.047  4.462   27.5    ab
    13.043000 desg  -4.239  4.366   27.5    ab
    13.050000 desr  4.695   3.46    27.5    ab
    13.058000 desi  6.291   6.248   27.5    ab
    13.074000 desz  6.412   5.953   27.5    ab
    21.050000 desg  1.588   2.681   27.5    ab
    21.058000 desr  -0.6124 2.171   27.5    ab
```

Comment: I put your sample in a file and read it in with `df = pd.read_csv('test.dat', sep='\\s+', skiprows=1)`

Comment: [Read data (.dat file) with Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41025416/read-data-dat-file-with-pandas?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I messed around a little with your line and it did work with a little editing.
I just turned skiprows to 0
data = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\\s+', skiprows=0)
thanks a lot :D

Comment: As an aside, as indentation is very syntactically important to Python, when posting sample Python code please make sure that the indentation is formatted correctly.

Comment: I am still new and learning, I will keep that in mind from now on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to include the sep in data = pd.read_table() so that it will keep each column as separate column with specifying the type of sep as "\s+"

```
n=10
li=[]
for i in range(0,n):
    file = "training_data/%s.dat"%i # This way I can call each file automatically 
    data = pd.read_table(file, sep="\s+") # I convert the file to pandas compatible
    li.append(data) # I add the file into the empty list above
# now I have my list ready so I compress it into 1 file
all_data = pd.concat(li)
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be that `Table.read()` is not able to guess the format / delimiter of your data.  I'm able to read the included example (data in file 0) using `Table.read(file, format='ascii', data_start=2)` into a table with 6 columns, but I'm not sure the whitespace is being captured correctly.

I am suspicious that the example data in file 0 is not literally what you are reading, because without the `data_start=2` that file will show up with row 1 being "float64     str4    float64 float64 float64 str2".

One thing you can do is try `Table.read(file, format='ascii', data_start=2, guess=False)`.

Comment: I tried it and it did keep the shape of my files but the second problem still remained because I can't use the pd.concat() function for astropy table file type, unless there's a way to convert a list to pandas