# Pandas : read data with a NaN in first column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file test.txt containing following values:

```
0 -45  0.1664   
0 -45  0.6440  22.3
0 -45  0.4646  22.5
0 -45  0.7232  22.1
0 -45  0.8723  22.1
0 -45  1.0214  22.0
5 -45  1.1705  21.9
5 -45  1.3196  21.8
```

I would like to use pandas to read the file and get on matlab the following dataframe:

```
    0   1       2     3
0   0 -45  0.1664   NaN
1   0 -45  0.6440  22.3
2   0 -45  0.4646  22.5
3   0 -45  0.7232  22.1
4   0 -45  0.8723  22.1
5   0 -45  1.0214  22.0
6   5 -45  1.1705  21.9
7   5 -45  1.3196  21.8
```

I've dont this :

```
data = pd.read_csv("test.txt",delim_whitespace=True,skip_blank_lines=False,header=None)
```

But it gives me this:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 2, saw 4
```

Do I have to add a parameter inside the read_csv function ? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: your file is csv?..

Comment: no it's a notpad++ file and I saved it as .dat

Comment: like this ?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41025416/read-data-dat-file-with-pandas

Comment: yeah but reading it from a file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a example , replace temp with the name file ...and import StringIO:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""0 -45  0.1664
0 -45  0.6440  22.3
0 -45  0.4646  22.5
0 -45  0.7232  22.1
0 -45  0.8723  22.1
0 -45  1.0214  22.0
5 -45  1.1705  21.9
5 -45  1.3196  21.8"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp),
                 sep="\s+",
                 usecols=[0,1,2,3],
                 names=['0','1','2','3'],
                 skip_blank_lines=False)

print (df)
```

Comment: yes , just replace ..and if you cant ...share me you example file here https://www.transferbigfiles.com/

Comment: can you share me your file ?

Comment: It's seems finally to work with sep="\t". Thanks :)