# Reading .dat file through pandas.read_csv( ) gives unicode error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, file-conversion

I've a set of .dat files and I'm not sure what type pf data they carry (mostly non video, audio content - should be a mix of integer, text and special characters). I came to learn that we read .dat files using pandas read_csv or read_table into Python and I tried the below

```
DATA = pd.read_csv(r'file_path\Data.dat', header=None)
```

below is the error I get

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes
> in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

I've tried the solutions listed from around including Stack overflow and blogs, and tried the below options too, but none of them worked

1. Used Double quotes for filepath instead of single quote *(pd.read_csv(r"filepath"))*
2. Use double backslash instead of single backslash
3. Use forward slash
4. Use double backslash only at the beginning of the filepath, something like C:\User\folder....
5. Tried a few encodings like utf-8, ascii, latin-1 etc., and the error for all the above is "*EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file*"
6. Tried without **r** in the read_csv argument. Didn't work
7. Tried 'sep='\s+', also set skiprows too. No use

One thing to mention is that one of my folder name has numbers apart from text. Does that create this issue by any chance?

Can someone highlight what I need to do...thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like you need to define the seperator value ```pd.read_csv(sep=)``` Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41025416/read-data-dat-file-with-pandas

Comment: @Nohman I've tried sep= as well earlier and I get the same error "SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape" I gave it a try once again to confirm but it didn't work

Comment: Both read_csv and read_table are for reading a table data with N rows x M columns. Unless your dat file is in that format, it is impossible to read.

Comment: Check how many spaces you have between the columns. Make sure it is consistent. Would be helpful to have a look at how your .dat file looks like